# CMIS for FileNet SOAP services

Tags: cmis

Is there any difference between `deleteObject` and `removeObjectFromFolder` CMIS SOAP services?

(other than that we can specify a `folderId` for `removeObjectFromFolder` in the request?)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: In general, I would start by reading the corresponding documentation. That should be your primary source of information.

Answer (score 0):

delete object deletes the specific object

removeObjectFromFolder is relevant for multi filing scenarios where it removes the existing non folder fileable object from folder.

Please read CMIS specification to get the full understanding

http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html